# What does "(By|Function)" mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium

At the very beginning I'd like to say that I'm not a "native speaker" of Javascript.

I'm writing UI automation tests in Selenium Webdriver and I try to understand the framework as much as possible. In [the documentation of Selenium Webdriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html) there is a description of `WebElement` class. The class has a method called `findElement` and this method passes a `locator` parameter. Type of the parameter is `(By|Function)`. I don't understand `(By|Function)` notation. What exactly is the type of `locator` parameter? Is it object of some class?  What does it mean? At the end, I can just say that `By` is another class in Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: It seems to refer to passing in either a function or the `By.tagName` type option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Selenium documentation, the notation `(A|B)` means "`A` or `B`". So `(By|Function)` means that the `locator` parameter is expected to be of type `By` or of type `Function`. `Function` is the standard JavaScript type name for something that is a function. `By` is a Selenium class that, according to [the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/by_exports_By.html): "Describes a mechanism for locating an element on the page."

The documentation page for [`findElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html) shows examples of using each of these argument types.

Answer (score 2):

This is not standard JavaScript syntax, but a syntax made up for the purpose of documenting types. There are a few different third-party syntaxes for types in JavaScript documentation: [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) (whose syntax is identical to the better-documented [Closure Type System](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System) for the Google Closure Compiler), [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), and [Flow](https://flow.org/).

In the case of `(By|Function)`, it doesn't matter what syntax this is, because `|` means the same in each of them. `|` means “or”, in analogy to `||`, the “or” operator in JavaScript. `Function` means any function such as `function() { console.log('hi') }`. `By` is specific to Selenium – if you click in it in the Selenium documentation you linked, you will find it’s a link to [Class `By`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/by_exports_By.html), which is a class you can construct using the JavaScript API.